# Filtering, string splitting and replacing the values in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which have income statements, I want to filter out the dataframe which have more than 500 yearly income, then correct them into monthly and yearly column.

In 2nd row, income is 300_100 (yearly_monthly) but its wrong in monthly column, so I want to change that after splitting the income column.

| ID | yearly | monthly | income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 200 | 100_200 |
| 2 | 500 | 100 | 300_100 |
| 3 | 1000 | 500 | 600_500 |
| 4 | 300 | 250 | 500_250 |

Output should be like

| ID | yearly | monthly | income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 200 | 100_200 |
| 2 | 300 | 100 | 300_100 |
| 3 | 600 | 500 | 600_500 |
| 4 | 300 | 250 | 500_250 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  separate(income, into = c("yearly", "monthly"), remove = F, convert = T) %>% 
  inner_join(df, by = "ID") %>% 
  mutate(yearly = if_else(yearly.y > 500, yearly.x, yearly.y)) %>% 
  select(ID, yearly, monthly = monthly.x, income = income.x)

#>   ID yearly monthly  income
#> 1  1    100     200 100_200
#> 2  2    500     100 300_100
#> 3  3    600     500 600_500
#> 4  4    300     250 500_250
```

Comment: This will work for every data, but I want only for greater than 500

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are wanting exactly, @SatyabanSahoo? The output of my solution coincides *exactly* with what you indicated, in your original question, as desired output!

Comment: I dont want any change if yearly income is greater than 500, whereas I want only changes as described if yearly income is greater than 500.

Comment: Could you please update your desired output in your original questions?

Comment: I have added one more record at the last, please check

Comment: My updated solution does what you want. Please, check it out, @SatyabanSahoo.

Comment: Thanks I got it now.. Just missing `inner_join`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246569/discussion-between-satyaban-sahoo-and-pauls).